# How to check whether the process results any error or not in Java?

Tags: java, process

I am making IDE related program in JavaFx that runs C,C++,Python, etc. code.
And when there is any compile time/runtime error in user's code, it shows some stack overflow related error's answer in a pop up window. But, how can I know there is whether error or not?

My code snippet is here -

```
public BufferedReader buildCode(File file)
    {
        String dirname = file.getParent();
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        String objectFileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName);
        String command = "gcc " + filePath + " -o " + dirname + "/" + objectFileName;
        BufferedReader stdInput;// = new BufferedReader(null);
        try
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String compileResult;
            while ((compileResult = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(compileResult);

            while ((compileResult = stdErr.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(compileResult);
            return stdInput;
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            //noinspection ThrowablePrintedToSystemOut
            System.out.println(io);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I guess I have to do something like checking `stdErr`, whether it is null or not. But, I don't sure that if there is nothing as error it assigned `EOF` in `stdErr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to parse process's output. GCC [will return non-zero exit code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) if something went wrong:

> Normally the gcc program exits with the code of 1 if any phase of the compiler returns a non-success return code. If you specify -pass-exit-codes, the gcc program instead returns with the numerically highest error produced by any phase returning an error indication. The C, C++, and Fortran front ends return 4 if an internal compiler error is encountered.

So, you can just check the exit code:

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

process.waitFor();

final result = process.exitValue();

if(0 != result) {
  ...
}
```